# How can I change my shell every time I log in to bash by editing .cshrc file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to set my default shell to bash (existing: csh). I am not allowed to use `chsh`.

Comment: If your company insists that you use `csh`, it's time to switch companies.

Comment: As this is not a programming question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic], it is off topic for Stack Overflow. For general operating system or application support, you may be able to find help on [su] or [unix.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: When everybody else uses `csh`, who will edit your code when you are sick/on holiday? Try to be part of the team and the team should (try to) switch.

Comment: What act of crime did you poor fellow commit, that your company forces to you to use csh as punishment? As for the comment by WalterA, the problem is not editing the _code_, because you are here asking about an interactive use of shell. Of course using csh for programming is as painful, but that's a different problem. In your `.cshrc`, you could do a `exec bash -l`. I don't know enought about _csh_, but it could be that you have to guard this statement by checking that you are really inside an **interactive** shell, and not inside some shell script which happens to source .cshrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `bash` on the first line of your `.cshrc`. This will immediately launch bash when you start a `csh` session. If you want to get back to `csh` for some reason, you can just type `exit` or `Ctrl-D` into the bash session.